# Use of undeclared identifier (Alert view with actions)

Tags: ios, uialertview, xcode4.5

I have a UIAlertView with buttons and I am trying to make these buttons execute an action.  The problem is I have an "undeclared identifier" in my method.

THE ISSUE I SEE http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28qvhom&s=6

THE CODE

The alert view

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Well done!"
    message: @"You got all 20 in Time: x"
    delegate:nil
    cancelButtonTitle:nil
    otherButtonTitles:@"Save and Quit", @"Quit", nil];


[alert show];}
```

the void

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView* )alertView 
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex         

{

    if(buttonIndex==0) {/*some action */ }
    else if(butonIndex==1){/*some action */}

}


     //I aso have <UIAlertViewDelegate> in my .h file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `else if(butonIndex==1)` you're missing the second "t" in the word button.

For future reference, Xcode's "Fix-It" feature will fix trivial mistakes like this for you.

[image]

Click the red circle to activate the fix-it menu then simply hit enter.

**EDIT:**

Do this:

```
- (void)myMethod{

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView* )alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

}
```

Not this:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView* )alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {

    }
}
```

If this isn't the case, then you are missing a closing brace "}" at the end of the method before the alert view delegate.

Comment: thank you for your time, but it still has not sorted out the issue. This is what I see http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wa2ijq&s=6

Comment: @JeevanThandi Then what exactly is the problem? You stated above that it was an undeclared identifier error which was fixed my correcting the spelling of "buttonIndex".

Comment: @JeevanThandi You placed the alertView delegate method inside another method, see my edit.

Comment: I do not see how it is in any other method as there is only one method (alertView)

Comment: You are placing the alertview (void) inside either another void or and ibaction.

Comment: I LOVE YOU MAN THANK YOU SO MUCH.  MAN I AM STUPID!!!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! IT WORKS :)

Comment: If my solution helped you then please be sure the mark my answer as correct :)